# Replace all the occurences of a characrer after Nth occurence in every line of a file in UNIX

Tags: string, unix, replace, sed, character

Supposing I have a document in which all lines are formatted like this :

```
1;23;3453;12312;32423;qwrewre;werwer
ert1;23;jdkj;seiuryy8743;874w65;hjfd;1234
df;23;3453;12312;sdjh;qwrewre;werwer
```

How do I use sed to replace the all after 2nd occurrences of **semicolon(;)** with a **pipe(|)** so that the document will look like:

```
1;23;3453|12312|32423|qwrewre|werwer
ert1;23;jdkj|seiuryy8743|874w65|hjfd|1234
df;23;3453|12312|sdjh|qwrewre|werwer
```

I tried using `sed 's/;/|/19g` but that replaced all the semicolons with pipe.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 6):

By doing this:

```
$ echo '1;23;3453;12312;32423;qwrewre;werwer' | sed 's/;/|/3g'
1;23;3453|12312|32423|qwrewre|werwer
```

Comment: Much better than my answer!  Didn't know you could specify which match to start on like that.